# How to give a div a hover and active state on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i've got a div which is black, when I hover over it, it turns green. when clicked, I want it to stay green also.

normale state: black

hover state: green

active state: green

and when its active `(green)`, I want to hover over it which makes the div black again.

i can't seem to get this active state work and in reverse.

thanks in advance!

Here is my fiddle: [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/AfR49/)

Comment: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AfR49/)

Comment: According to code you'll be having multiple IDs of same `#profile`, but remember IDs must be **unique**

Comment: ***when its active (green), I want to hover over it...*** it's a little confusing, when it's active, it means your mouse should be held down and maybe still hovers over the div.

Comment: meaning in active state its green. but when hover over it again it will turn black and by clicking it again it stays black.

Comment: @Junske you may interpret the `active` as class while I thought of it as state (which exists only while the mouse is held down).

Comment: @Junske I'm still not sure if I understand your problem correctly, try this http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/AfR49/8/ if it's what you want.

Comment: @KingKing thanks for this, I didnt knew it was possible with this simple CSS.

Comment: @Junske it's not just CSS, it also has a little jQuery code :)

Comment: @KingKing I saw that later yes. I was too happy it worked! thanks!

Answer (score 11):

You can do it without jQuery in pure CSS. Give your DIV a tabIndex so it can receive focus:

```
<div id="profile" tabindex="0"></div>
```

And add `:focus` class selection:

```
#profile:hover, #profile:focus{
    background: green;    
}
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AfR49/10/**

This way the color "stick" after the click. (If I understood your requirement correctly). If you click elsewhere - color returns to the original

Comment: you bette use tabindex="0" so you do not disturb the regular 'tab flow' within the page.

Comment: it's near my question. but I dont want to click elsewhere on the page, just on the DIV to make it change back to its original.

Comment: @Junske on what condition? You click the div and you still hover over DIV. What would be the condition to change it back? Move mouse? Or it should stay green while the mouse button is pressed and return to black when it is released?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter its like when I hover and focus on it, it turns green. lets say: after that my mouse will move somewhere else and return back to the green div which was earlier black. now when hover and focus on the green div i want it to turn black again.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add styling for the `:hover` state on the `.active` class (note that I'm using `tomato` instead of `black` as that's the colour you've used in your demo):

```css
#profile.active:hover {
    background: tomato;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/AfR49/5/).

I'm not sure what you're wanting to achieve here though:

```
$('#profile').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
```

If you're wanting the element to toggle on and off of `.active` with each click, you can simply:

```
$(this).toggleClass('active');
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have the following div

```
<div id="divSample"></div>
```

Then, you will need the following CSS:

```
#divSample {
    background-color:Black;
    height:300px;
    width:500px;
}
#divSample:hover {
    background-color:Green;
}

#divSample:active {
    background-color:Green;
}
```

You can see this here: http://jsfiddle.net/h4aVW/

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score -1):

Create a class `.active` containing the styling you want and add it to the div with jQuery.

The you can easily style your div in the two states.

```
.normal {background-color:black}
.normal:hover {background-color: green}
.active {background-color: green}
.active:hover {background-color: black}
```